# Как правильно переписать Object класс Kotlin на Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ads

Пишу пред.загрузку NativeAds, идея в следующем, на первом экране запускается метод, который загружает рекламу и при переходе на второй экран, реклама сразу показывается. Я написал код на Kotlin, вроде работает правильно, но не знаю как правильно сделать это на джава, помогите пожалуйста.
Вот мой Kotlin код:

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        MobileAds.initialize(this) {}

        refreshAd(this)
        Handler().postDelayed({
            startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity2::class.java))
        }, 5000)
    }

}
```

SecondActivity2

```
class SecondActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second2)

        val ad_frame: FrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.ad_frame);

        val adView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_unified, null) as NativeAdView
        showAds(adView, ad_frame);

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        destroyNativeAd()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

activity_second2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity2">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Preload

```
object Preload {
    const val ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID = "/6499/example/native"

    var currentNativeAd: NativeAd? = null
    fun populateNativeAdView(nativeAd: NativeAd, adView: NativeAdView) {
        adView.mediaView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_media)

        adView.headlineView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_headline)
        adView.bodyView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_body)
        adView.callToActionView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_call_to_action)
        adView.iconView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_app_icon)
        adView.priceView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_price)
        adView.starRatingView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_stars)
        adView.storeView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_store)
        adView.advertiserView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_advertiser)

        (adView.headlineView as TextView).text = nativeAd.headline
        adView.mediaView.setMediaContent(nativeAd.mediaContent)

        if (nativeAd.body == null) {
            adView.bodyView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            adView.bodyView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            (adView.bodyView as TextView).text = nativeAd.body
        }

        if (nativeAd.callToAction == null) {
            adView.callToActionView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            adView.callToActionView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            (adView.callToActionView as Button).text = nativeAd.callToAction
        }

        if (nativeAd.icon == null) {
            adView.iconView.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            (adView.iconView as ImageView).setImageDrawable(
                nativeAd.icon.drawable
            )
            adView.iconView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        if (nativeAd.price == null) {
            adView.priceView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            adView.priceView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            (adView.priceView as TextView).text = nativeAd.price
        }

        if (nativeAd.store == null) {
            adView.storeView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            adView.storeView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            (adView.storeView as TextView).text = nativeAd.store
        }

        if (nativeAd.starRating == null) {
            adView.starRatingView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            (adView.starRatingView as RatingBar).rating = nativeAd.starRating!!.toFloat()
            adView.starRatingView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        if (nativeAd.advertiser == null) {
            adView.advertiserView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            (adView.advertiserView as TextView).text = nativeAd.advertiser
            adView.advertiserView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd)

        val vc = nativeAd.mediaContent.videoController
        
        if (vc.hasVideoContent()) {
            vc.videoLifecycleCallbacks = object : VideoController.VideoLifecycleCallbacks() {
                override fun onVideoEnd() {
                    super.onVideoEnd()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun refreshAd(activity: MainActivity) {
        val builder = AdLoader.Builder(activity, ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID)

        builder.forNativeAd { nativeAd ->
//            var activityDestroyed = false
//            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
//                activityDestroyed = isDestroyed
//            }
//            if (activityDestroyed || isFinishing || isChangingConfigurations) {
//                nativeAd.destroy()
//                return@forNativeAd
//            }

            currentNativeAd?.destroy()
            currentNativeAd = nativeAd

        }

        val videoOptions = VideoOptions.Builder().build()

        val adOptions = NativeAdOptions.Builder()
            .setVideoOptions(videoOptions)
            .build()

        builder.withNativeAdOptions(adOptions)

        val adLoader = builder.withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError: LoadAdError) {
            }

            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded()
                Log.i("NativeAds", "onAdLoaded()")
            }
        }).build()

        adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())

    }

    fun showAds(adView: NativeAdView, ad_frame: FrameLayout) {
        currentNativeAd?.let { populateNativeAdView(it, adView) }
        ad_frame.removeAllViews()
        ad_frame.addView(adView)
    }

    fun destroyNativeAd() {
        currentNativeAd?.destroy()
        Log.i("NativeAds", "$currentNativeAd")
    }
}
```

Comment: Что именно вызывает проблемы? Первых два класса вообще ничего чисто котлиновского не содержат. Просто читаете Kotlin, пишете Java построчно. Третий да, тут придется свою имплементацию Singleton на Java написать. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#object-declarations-overview

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja классы активити я добавил чтобы было понятно чего я пытаюсь добиться, знаю что нужен Singlton, но не знаю как правильно переписать object Preload()

Comment: Просто замените object на class. А все методы и переменные сделайте статическими